# Match everything except newline, space and tab

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I want to match everything except a newline, space and tab. I know there is `\S`, but it says to not use it in char classes, so how can I say I want everything except `\S`? What I want to check is that the string I have has at least any visible char.

```
Test 1234      --> should be found
____ (spaces)  --> should not be found
```

Comment: "Test 1234" contains a space. "\S+" will not match it all, but can mach both individual words if run for multiple matches.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make sure the string doesn't consist entirely of whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\S` is enough, which Matches anything BUT a whitespace.

```
preg_match('/\S/', $subject);
```

Comment: Right, in my case its enough to see if there is at least something that it finds...I did not see that in the first place, thanks.

Comment: Hmm... tested [online](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) where it worked as `preg_match('/\\S/', $subject);`

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev `/\S/` is just fine, and your link gives no info.

Comment: That's interesting. That site, if I run `echo preg_match('/\S/', "S"); echo preg_match('/\S/', "1"); echo preg_match('/\\S/', "1");` outputs "101". I wonder why the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Character classes are these: `[]` things with all their contents, as per [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so outside of square brackets this should match just fine and do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/([^\n\s]+)/', $str, $m);

print_r($m);
```